# Fetching data from cursor in mybatis

Tags: plsql, mybatis

I am quite new to mybatis and have been trying to call a function returning a cursor from mybatis.
Here are some code snippets:

PL/SQL Function :

```
FUNCTION student_fetch(
  p_id      VARCHAR2,
  p_usr_id       VARCHAR2,
  p_program_code VARCHAR2)
 RETURN t_students_cursor
IS
 cur t_students_cursor;
 --v_cnt INT;
BEGIN
 --check_student_info_permission(p_osis_id, p_usr_id, p_program_code, v_cnt);
 --IF v_cnt  > 0 THEN
 OPEN cur FOR SELECT srec.First_Name, srec.Last_Name, srec.Middle_Initial,
```

XML entry :

```
   <resultMap id="accountDetailResult" type="student">
     <result property="firstName" column="First_Name" />
    <result property="lastName" column="Last_Name" />

    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAccountDetail" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
   { #{t_students_cursor,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} = 
    call students.student_fetch(#{osisId,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{userId,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},#{programCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN})}

 </select>
```

POJO Class :

```
public class Student {



    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;


    private String emailAddress;

    private String daytimeTelephoneNumber;

    private String id;

    private String userId;

    private String programCode;
```

Mapper Interface :

```
void getAccountDetail(@Param("map") Map<String, Object> parameter);
```

Tester Class :

```
 Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("p_d", "214996787");
    param.put("p_usr_id", "admin");
    param.put("p_program_code", null);
    productServiceObj.getAccountDetail(param);
    Student st = (Student)param.get("t_students_cursor");
```

Exception :

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may involve com.example.services.ProductServices.getAccountDetail-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:61)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:38)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:66)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:35)
    at $Proxy1.getAccountDetail(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.runner.AppTester.main(AppTester.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:870)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:960)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3390)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4223)
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the full definition of your PL/SQL function, including how `t_students_cursor` is defined.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it dependent on the cursor part?Can you please tell me the relation between the cursor returned and mybatis?

Comment: My answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666856/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-with-mybatis/43685072#43685072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A catchy tweak:

```
#{t_students_cursor,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} =  call students.student_fetch(#{osisId,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, #{userId,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN},#{programCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN})}
```

is the correct way. "call" should be inline with the "#{t_students_cursor,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT,resultMap=accountDetailResult,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet} = "