# How can I use oracle merge statement using Mybatis?

Tags: oracle, merge, tags, mybatis

I couldn't see any mapper(mybatis-3-mapper.dtd) where I can call a merge statement in mybatis.

I saw tags for update, insert, delete and SQL

Anyone please suggest how to use oracle merge statement in Mybatis.

Answer (score 7):

Call the merge as below:-

```
<update id="exceMerge" parameterType="hashmap">
        MERGE INTO USERS U USING DUAL ON (U.PROPERTY_NAME=#{prop_name}) 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET U.PROPERTYVALUE=#{prop_value}, U.MESSAGE=#{message,javaType=String,jdbcType=CLOB}
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT(PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTYVALUE, MESSAGE) VALUES (#{prop_name},#{prop_value},#{message,javaType=String,jdbcType=CLOB})
</update>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a stored procedure, although you may also try just pasting your code into `<update>` tag.

Calling stored procedures in MyBatis is easy, after you define a procedure in your DB simply follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666856/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-with-mybatis).

Note that in case where your procedure doesn't return any parameters, the procedure call should be in `<update>` tag (instead of `<select>`, as in example).